# Android library alternative to Samsung SCanvas

Tags: android, images

Currently have an app that uses Samsung SCanvas with the SPen to

- draw lines and
- put images and text on the screen.

Currently the SCanvas will only work on Samsung Galaxy devices and I would like to port the app over to other devices. I have created an app that uses an Android Canvas to draw lines, images, and text but I would like some of the extra features that come with the SCanvas like

- being able to move, resize, and rotate the images and text after they have been added to the Canvas.

Another great feature of the SCanvas is how it

- allows you to animate what the user created.

Does anyone know if there is a **Android library** out there that would allow me to create some of these same features of the SCanvas?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Just in case you wonder: I've slightly edited your question to make the key-points stand out clearer, which hopefully helps to draw in the impatient as well (which otherwise might skip over the long text block). Hope that's fine with you. If not, you can always [edit] your post to re-adjust it. Good luck!